# swift protocol init func error with SpriteKit

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Can anyone show me what wrong with my code?

[code in playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7evFO.png)

[error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfGtL.png)

```
protocol PersonWithName: class  {
    var personName: String {get set}

    init(name: String)
}

class NameCard<PersonType: SKSpriteNode where PersonType: PersonWithName> {

    var person: PersonType

    init() {
        self.person = PersonType(name: "No Name") // this line error.
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post code and errors in screenshots. Please [edit] your post, copy-paste the code and error messages, then select them and press Ctrl+K to format

Comment: @Arc676 I have posted my code in text now. Please give me a hand.

Comment: @EricD. The solution by compiler is not what I want. I have the protocol defined required initial function, but I can't call it with the generic type conform to the protocol. That the problem.

Comment: For future questions you should include the error in the question, not simply label the line with "the error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For shorter explanation I replaced `SKSpriteNode` with `Any` because you have to deal with the designated `init()` of `SKSpriteNode` later in more detail.. For more details on Initializer Requirements in protocols, take a look at [this section of Apple's Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID272)

```
protocol PersonWithName: class  {
    var personName: String {get set}
    init(name: String)
}

class NameCard<PersonType: Any where PersonType: PersonWithName> {

    var person: PersonType

    init() {
        self.person = PersonType(name: "No Name")
    }
}

class ExampleClass: PersonWithName {
    var personName: String = ""

    required init(name: String) {
        personName = name
    }
}

var test = NameCard<ExampleClass>()
print(test.person.personName) // "No Name"
```

Comment: But my purpose is to enforce the PersonType has an initial function accept a parameter with name of String type. This example is just a simple demo base on one scene of my project. Your idea can only solve the cases that the class can change its properties conveniently after init. But some classes that their structure was determinate when initialized and cannot change more easily than create a new instance.

Comment: And the problem showed by complier is, the PersonType has no initial function with name label. But as my PersonType defined to conform to PersonWithName protocol. PersonType has to have the initial function with name label. I thought the complier was wrong.

Comment: What the compiler was referring to, was the `init(imageNamed: String)` method of the `SKSpriteNode` class (because the next inferred `init()` method was provided by `SKSpriteNode`).

Comment: But if NameCard doesn't conform to SKSpriteNode, I cannot use the properties of SKSpriteNode like position, size directly(unless use Type Casting). The code can be run correctly with PersonType inheriting NSObject too. My solution now is to create a protocol SKSpriteNodeProtocol with some properties I need. And add `extension SKSpriteNode : SKSpriteNodeProtocol {}` to make SKSpriteNode conform to my custom protocol. But this solution is not what I want. I'm so upset by this question now (: Than you for you solution all the same.

Comment: I just replaced it to boil the code down to the essentials of this problem. For you to use you need to change `Any` back to `SKSpriteNode` but then take care of the designated init :)

Comment: But the error was still there if i change Any back to SKSpriteNode. I cannot paste my code here. I posted it to the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

My current imperfect solution.@FlorianWeßling

```
protocol PersonWithName: class  {
    var personName: String {get set}
    init(name: String)
}

protocol SKSpriteNodeProtocol {
    var position: CGPoint {get set}
    var size: CGSize {get set}
    //or more properties you want
}

class NameCard<PersonType: SKSpriteNodeProtocol where PersonType: PersonWithName> {

    var person: PersonType

    init() {
        self.person = PersonType(name: "No Name")
    }
}

extension SKSpriteNode : SKSpriteNodeProtocol {}

class ExampleClass: SKSpriteNode, PersonWithName {
    var personName: String = ""

    required init(name: String) {
        personName = name
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeZero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

var test = NameCard<ExampleClass>()
print(test.person.personName) // "No Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is only important to access a `SKSpriteNode` within the `NameCard` then you might add a simple variable `node` and remove the inheritance from `SKSpriteNode`:

```
protocol PersonWithName {
    var personName: String {get set}
    init(name: String)
}

class NameCard<PersonType: PersonWithName> {

    var person: PersonType
    var node: SKSpriteNode?

    init() {
        self.person = PersonType(name: "No Name")
    }
}

class ExampleClass: PersonWithName {
    var personName: String = ""

    required init(name: String) {
        personName = name
    }
}

var test = NameCard<ExampleClass>()
print(test.person.personName) // "No Name"
print(test.node?.description) // currently nil
```